# Angularjs directive and string.format

Tags: javascript, c#, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a JSON like this

```
{textTemplate:"Name：{0}，Phone：{1}",controls:[{id:1,Name:"Name",type:"text"},{id:2,Name:"Phone",type:"text"}]}
```

I have no idea how to use the directive to replace string to html control

My Expect :

```
Name : <input type='text' name='Name' /> Phone : <input type='text' Name='Phone' />
```

Comment: Dear, mention your complete function code

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `directive` who wraps an input something like:

```
<div my-directive-input name="model.Name" phone="model.Phone"></div>
```

The `template` should be the one you presented here.
The `directive` should replace the div with the new `template`.

You should download the data from your server and bind it to your model(in this example it's straight on your model - but this can change due to your demands.